# pylance: import could not be resolved

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, virtualenv

I am using vscode with virtual environment (conda) to write python files on my mac.

I keep seeing import problems from pylance for specific third party AND official libraries (for example pyproj, geopy for third party, math for preinstalled).
for each file the errors/warnings look as follows:
[image: screenshot of problems]

I am sure that these packages are in my virtual environment (they are included in the `conda list` packages.

Although so far it seems to me as a cosmetic issue, removing these warnings would be very helpful. 
Here (https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/blob/main/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#unresolved-import-warnings) there are some explanations but I did not fully udnerstand the issue or managed to resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following configuration in **setting.json** to remove these warnings

```json
    "python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
        "reportMissingImports": "none",
        "reportUndefinedVariable": "none"
    },
```

Use `ctrl + shift +p` to open the command palette. Search **Settings**, there are two **settings.json** files here. **User** works globally, **Workspace** works only on the current workspace. If the same configuration exists in both files, **Workspace** will override the settings in **User**.

[image]

Comment: where should the setting.json file be?

Comment: This isn't a solution to the problem.  This is like having a bullet would and masking it with morphine.  Hiding the symptoms is NOT a cure.